# PHP copy function and Apache group

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a web application that generate some php files for new members in sub-directories, I'm using PHP copy function to do that, but members web pages gives 500 Internal Server Error, and the script is working fine if uploaded by FTP, with the hosting account, or the root account.

I think the problem is with the "apache apache" group, because after uploading files with the "root root" group, files are working fine, please help!

this is the function used to copy the whole files in my directory to users ones :

```
function smartCopy($source, $dest, $options=array('folderPermission'=>0775,'filePermission'=>0775)) 
    { 
        $result=false; 

        if (is_file($source)) { 
            if ($dest[strlen($dest)-1]=='/') { 
                if (!file_exists($dest)) { 
                    cmfcDirectory::makeAll($dest,$options['folderPermission'],true); 
                } 
                $__dest=$dest."/".basename($source); 
            } else { 
                $__dest=$dest; 
            } 
            $result=copy($source, $__dest); 
            chmod($__dest,$options['filePermission']); 

        } elseif(is_dir($source)) { 
            if ($dest[strlen($dest)-1]=='/') { 
                if ($source[strlen($source)-1]=='/') { 
                    //Copy only contents 
                } else { 
                    //Change parent itself and its contents 
                    $dest=$dest.basename($source); 
                    @mkdir($dest); 
                    chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']); 
                } 
            } else { 
                if ($source[strlen($source)-1]=='/') { 
                    //Copy parent directory with new name and all its content 
                    @mkdir($dest,$options['folderPermission']); 
                    chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']); 
                } else { 
                    //Copy parent directory with new name and all its content 
                    @mkdir($dest,$options['folderPermission']); 
                    chmod($dest,$options['filePermission']); 
                } 
            } 

            $dirHandle=opendir($source); 
            while($file=readdir($dirHandle)) 
            { 
                if($file!="." && $file!="..") 
                { 
                     if(!is_dir($source."/".$file)) { 
                        $__dest=$dest."/".$file; 
                    } else { 
                        $__dest=$dest."/".$file; 
                    } 
                    //echo "$source/$file ||| $__dest<br />"; 
                    $result=smartCopy($source."/".$file, $__dest, $options); 
                } 
            } 
            closedir($dirHandle); 

        } else { 
            $result=false; 
        } 
        return $result; 
    }
```

Notice : there are no problem with permissions.

Comment: What errors do you get? A 500 error doesn't really make sense if it were a permissions problem. Do you have access to Apache's error log?

Comment: yup, 500 error, and I'm the server owner.

Comment: And what do the logs have to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this function to solve my problem :

```
$oldmask = umask(0);
mkdir("apps/$appid", 0755);
umask($oldmask);
```